# Annotator.js load annotations from json

Tags: javascript, json, annotations

I am trying to develop a website in which i need some annotations.
I have found a great js library, annotator.js, but i can't seem to be able to start it.

I am trying to highlight some annotations when the page is loaded, but i can't seem to get it right. I do receive a JS error saying  .slice is not a function, but no matter how i change the json object, i cant get it to work.

Can anyone help me understand how it works ? I have been through their documentation but i dont seem to be able to load anything.

THis is what i have so far:

```
<div id="annon">
    Lorem ipsum
</div>

<script>
var annotator = $('#annon').annotator();
annotator.annotator('loadAnnotations', 
{"rows": 
[{
  "quote": "Lorem",
  "ranges":
      [{
          "endOffset": 5,
          "startOffset": 0,
          "end": "/",
          "start": "/"
      }],
  "text": "Lorem", "id": 1
 }],
,"total": 1}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to get the annotated word to light up.
I have done testing in the browser to play around with the structure of the object so that i can correct the RANGE property in particular. This is my solution:

```
annotator.loadAnnotations([{
"id": "39fc339cf058bd22176771b3e3187329",
"created": "2011-05-24T18:52:08.036814",
"updated": "2011-05-26T12:17:05.012544",
"text": "This is a comment",                
"quote": "Lorem",         
"ranges": 
[{
  "start": "/div[1]",         
  "end": "/div[1]",           
  "startOffset": 17,                    
  "endOffset": 22                     
}]
```

What i am having problems undestanding is why the startOffset is 17 considering LOREM is the first word in the div.

If anyone can explain that, that would be great !

**LE** 
I have identified the problem with 17-22. It was the actual spaces in the div, which my IDE added when i've put them on a new line.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, the object you are passing in to the annotator is incorrect.  You want to pass in an array of annotation objects (format here: http://docs.annotatorjs.org/en/stable/annotation-format.html)
Example:

```
    var annotator = $('#annon').annotator();
    annotator.annotator('loadAnnotations', [{
        "quote": "Lorem",
        "ranges": [{
            "endOffset": 5,
            "startOffset": 0,
            "end": "/",
            "start": "/"
        }],
        "text": "A comment.",
        "id": 1
    }]);
```

However when I run this, annotator complains about the XPath you are setting in the start/end ranges.  You'll have to figure out how to set the ranges correctly to get the text to highlight properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont get the error anymore. However, i have changed the end and start to '' and added the tags attribute with a value of ["testTag"], but the LOREM word still does not light up. Do i need to do anything specific ?